# Confused about ASP.NET MVC and Server Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I read that one cannot use ASP.NET MVC with Server Control which have ViewState including TextBox ?

http://forums.asp.net/t/1216834.aspx

> Server controls that do not require
>   ViewState to fully function will work
>   in MVC, but anything that requires
>   PostBack to work properly will not.
>
> So bindable, read-only controls like
>   the Repeater will work, but input
>   controls like the DropDownList and
>   TextBox will not.

What should I use then if I cannot even use TextBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC both use a backend coding convention to render HTML markup.  In ASP.NET the convention is to use Control classes, and in ASP.NET MVC the convention is to use `HtmlHelper` extension methods.

The [TextBox ASP.NET Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx) with the following ASP.NET markup

```
 <asp:TextBox id="sample_tbx" Text="Sample Default Value" runat="server"  />
```

renders the following HTML markup

```
 <input type="text" name="sample_tbx" id="sample_tbx" value="Sample Default Value" />
```

To get the same result with an `HtmlHelper` extension method in an MVC View, the convention is to use the [`TextBox()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049.aspx).  For example,

```
 <%= Html.TextBox("sample_tbx", "Sample Default Value") %>
```

In either ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC, html markup can be written inline.  So, simply writing

```
 <input type="text" name="sample_tbx" id="sample_tbx" value="Sample Default Value" />
```

is valid for either ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 3):

You just use standard HTML input fields or HTML Helpers.

Comment: What the boring html field what a regression in progress :)

Comment: ASP.Net MVC is intended for those that don't think Server Controls & the required ViewState are progress but more a blight on humanity.